# Where are laravel cache stored while using array driver?

Tags: laravel

I have implemented query cached in my application  and my cache driver is array.But i dont know where the cached data is stored.

```
In config/cache.php
 'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),

In my .env
 CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

Comment: its not actually 'stored' anywhere, it is just held in an array in memory in the PHP process

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Can you tell me how can i see the cached query whether its really exist in memory?

Comment: it is in the cache store, just ask the store for it like you would no matter what driver you use ... `Cache::get(...)`

Comment: how can i clear this cache

Comment: @RabbiMahmud Probably by using Cache::flush()